# Fixed vs Have Fixed

Tags: present-perfect, simple-past

Suppose I am writing an email to let people know I fixed a bug (and committed the fix).

What should I write ?

> I *have fixed* the bug and committed the fix

or

> I *fixed* the bug and committed the fix.

P.S. I know the difference between Past Perfect and Simple Past in theory but I am not sure I can use them properly in practice.

Comment: the only difference in my mind is that _have fixed_ sounds like you just fixed it as a response to the bug report while _fixed_ could have been done at any time prior to today

Comment: With regard to the construction, I think the simple past is more common in these grey (sorry, gray) areas in the US than in the UK. Interestingly, I'm choosing to interpret the first alternative as an elision of _I have fixed the bug and I have committed the fix_ rather than _I have fixed the bug and I committed the fix_, symmetry being preserved in many constructions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with mplungjan.

I fixed the bug implies that it was done some time back, and on your own accord, unless you write the sentence as :

After I received the complaint, I fixed the problem...

It also seems like a general statement you are making, maybe in your daily report.

I have fixed the problem, sounds more like you are saying it in response to a complaint/report. It seems to imply :

I have (now) fixed the problem...

Answer (score 4):

The choice depends on the context, on what went on before in the dialogue and what was likely to follow. As others have said, the past tense implies that the fixing took place some while ago, whereas the present perfect suggests a more recent event and does so in a way that relates it to the current situation.

You don’t ask for comments on the second part of the sentence, but a native speaker would be unlikely to say ‘committed the fix’.

Comment: Oh – I thought it must be computerspeak. Does OP mean 'applied' then?

Comment: Perhaps it does. If so, I stand corrected.

Comment: No, I was just guessing. I'll investigate. (Mind you, I don't know how you can fix a bug _without_ actually 'applying the fix'.)

Comment: Yes: 'commit the fix' is idiomatic in the computer world. Now I've got to find out what it means. Perhaps OP means "'written a subroutine to correct the bug' and 'committed it' ".

Comment: Wikipedia: 'In computer science and data management, a commit is the making of a set of tentative changes permanent. A popular usage is at the end of a transaction. A commit is an act of committing.' So the verbal form follows. So 'committed the fix' is arguably not simply a repeat of 'fixed the bug' as I feared, but means 'fixed the bug permanently.'

Comment: Thanks. I don't think I'll be needing to use it much myself.

Comment: No bugs on Barrie.